# Iterar lista y que devuelva indice PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas,como  itero en una lista con un ciclo for como ejemplo. Y la variable del for me devuelva el indice de la lista en esa itereacion en vez del elemento. Un ejemplo aqui va.

```
array_1=["1","2","3"]
for i in array_1:
    print(i)
```

Se que en ese caso mi funcion print me devovlera el elemento en el cual esta iterando el for que seria un string. Pero como haria para que me devuelva el indice de ese elemento. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sencilla y bastante óptima sería usando la función [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), modificando un poco tu  ejemplo, sería así:

```
array_1=["A","B","C"]
for i, _ in enumerate(array_1):
    print("El valor de array[{0}] es {1}".format(i,array_1[i]))
```

Otra forma, se me ocurre, es usando [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) con la longitud de array

```
for i in range(len(array_1)):
    print("El valor de array[{0}] es {1}".format(i,array_1[i]))
```

En ambos casos la salida sería:

```
El valor de array[0] es A
El valor de array[1] es B
El valor de array[2] es C
```

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas de realizar lo que deseas o necesitas es utilizando range y len.

**len** es una función que permite contabilizar los elementos de una lista, en tanto que **range** permite crear una lista que va de 0 a n-1, donde *n* es el valor numérico que se pasa como argumento a la función.

Por ejemplo

l= range(10), genera la siguiente lista [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Aplicando esto a tu caso:

```
array_1=["1","2","3"]
for i in range(len(array_1)):
    print(i)
```

Dando como resultado:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar un contador antes del `for` y aumentarlo en cada iteración:

```
cont = 0
for i in array_1:
    print(cont)
    cont = cont + 1
```